# Swift the figure of photo changes after retrieve from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want user to choose a photo from album, showing it on one imageView and store it in NSUserDefaults. 
The below code means to retrieve this image from NSUserDefaults and show it in headSculptureImage

> ```
>     headSculptureImage.layer.cornerRadius = (headSculptureImage.frame.size.height)/2;
>     headSculptureImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
>     headSculptureImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;
> ```
>
> This three is used to make this imageView to be a circle

```
if let userHeadSculpture = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userHeadSculpture") {
    let image = UIImage(data: userHeadSculpture as! NSData)
    headSculptureImage.image = image
    headSculptureImage.layer.cornerRadius = (headSculptureImage.frame.size.height)/2;
    headSculptureImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    headSculptureImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;
}
```

The problem is when I choose a pic from album, it works like[image]

what I expected when I reopen app is as same as the pic above, but it showed as [image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried printing `headSculptureImage.frame.size` in both cases? Such a rhombus is typically caused by setting the corner radius higher than the half width. Please extend the question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you use constraints and use the `NSUserDefaults` code in `viewDidLoad`. If that is the case, since `viewDidLoad` is called before the constraints have loaded, your value of `headSculptureImage.frame.size.height` is a different one than what you would have with constraints, producing this sort of result.
In order to resolve that, try moving the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called after the constraints are all set up, to have the `cornerRadius` value exactly what you need.

Mind that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called quite frequently, so you might want to add some sort of a flag to make sure it is called only when you need it to.